# Using css3 animation and addClass to make a background flash when clicked

Tags: jquery, css, background, css-transitions, css-animations

When an action is processed, I want a certain div to flash a green background and then fade back to normal.  I don't want to load the heave jquery UI library.  What is the best way to do this?  (I know this post is similar to some others out there but I can't get it to work for this specific problem for some reason!)  Right now I am trying the following but it won't work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/R8c9Z/.

HTML:

```
<div id="flashMe">Click me to toggle class</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#flashMe").click(function () {
    $("#flashMe").toggleClass("flashNow");
});
```

CSS:

```
#flashMe {
  background:none;
}
.flashNow {
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  0% { background:green; }
  100% { background:none; }
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% { background:green; }
  100% { background:none; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/R8c9Z/3/

```
document.getElementById('flashMe').onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("flashNow");
});
```

You also missed some vendor prefixes.

```
.flashNow {
  animation-name: flash;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-name: flash;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
  from { background: green; }
  to  background: none; }
}
@keyframes flash {
  0% { background: green; }
  100% { background: none; }
}
```

Comment: how is this different?

Comment: @roboguy222 You said you wanted to get rid of jQuery.

Comment: Nope.  I don't want to use the UI plugin on top of jquery.  The regular library is fine.  Sorry for the confusion.  Thank you!  The prefixes did it.

Comment: @roboguy222 Ugh. I would recommend using neither. Vanilla JS FTW!

Comment: @bjb568 why would you recommend not using either?

Comment: @DennisMartinez It's better to know what you're doing than relying on a overweight library to hopefully not barf on IE 6.